# Quick method to find $|H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K}|$ starting from $|H \cap B \cap K|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose sets $S, H, K, B$. Let

$$\begin{align}
&|S| = 100 \\
&|H| = 57 \\
&|K| = 77 \\
&|B| = 66 \\
&|H\cap B| = 30 \\
&|H \cap K| = 40 \\
&|B \cap K| = 50
\end{align}$$.

The question asks to find

1. $|H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K}|$
2. $|K \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{H}|$
3. $|B \cap \overline{H} \cap \overline{K}|$

By inclusion-exclusion,

$$\begin{align}
&|H \cup B \cup K| = |H| + |B| + |K| - (|H \cap B| + |H \cap K| + |B \cap K) + |H \cap B \cap K| \\
&|H \cap B \cap K| =|H \cup B \cup K| - (|H| + |B| + |K|) + (|H \cap B| + |H \cap K| + |B \cap K)  \\
\end{align}$$

Is there a short way to find, for example, $|H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K}|$, starting from  $|H \cap B \cap K|$?

I did the following work to find $|H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K}|$, but
 I am looking for a quicker way to do this.
$$\begin{align}
&H = H \cap ((\overline{B} \cap \overline{K}) \cup (B \cup K))  \\
&H = (H \cap (\overline{B} \cap \overline{K})) \cup (H \cap (B \cup K)) \\
& (H \cap (\overline{B} \cap \overline{K})) = H -  (H \cap (B \cup K)) \\
& H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K} = H - (H \cap B) \cup (H \cap K) \\
& |H \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{K}| = |H| - (|(H \cap B)| + |(H \cap K)|) + |H \cap K \cap B| \\
& = 57 - (30 + 40) + 20 = 7 \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the quickest way is to draw a Venn diagram, calculate $|H\cap K\cap B|=20$, and fill in the cardinalities of the eight regions into which the diagram divides $S$. I very quickly get this:

[image]

I can now read off the answers; for instance, $|H\cap\overline{B}\cap\overline{K}|=7$. (In fact all three are $7$.)

Comment: That Venn diagram looks really good. Although, I have always been told that proof by pictures are bad.

Comment: @mathMajor: Here the picture is really just a convenient way to organize the calculations. Once you have it, you can transform them into algebraic calculations. In this case, for instance, filling in the $10$ is just observing that $$|H\cap B\cap\overline{K}|=|H\cap B|-|H\cap B\cap K|\;,$$ but it’s easier to do first on the diagram.